# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 when setting objective C block by Swift code

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

I have hybrid app (Swift app using Objective C code)
In the Swift code I set an array of blocks and run the blocks in ObjC code. But there is an EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 when the block should be run.

When I set the array of blocks in the ObjC code, everything is ok.

Any idea why is Swift so unhappy with running the blocks from the array?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. My array of blocks is a property. It was like this:

```
//Class.h - before fix

typedef BOOL (^TextReplacementDecisionBlock)(NSString *, NSRange, NSString *);

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *decisionBlocks; // led to EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

It was ok for Obj C but it was not enough for Swift. Swift needs more specific blocks to translate it correctly to the closures. Like this:

```
//Class.h - after fix

typedef BOOL (^TextReplacementDecisionBlock)(NSString *, NSRange, NSString *);

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<TextReplacementDecisionBlock> *decisionBlocks;
```